# the trait `WrapperTypeEncode` is not implemented for `ethereum_types::H256` & `ethereum_types::U256`

Tags: substrate-node-template, ethereum

I am using:

```
ethereum-type version = "0.12", codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"]}
scale-info = { version = "2.0.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
```

And latest `substrate-node-template` of branch `polkadot-v0.9.19`.
So I am trying to build the code , and for the above ethereum_types, getting `WrapperTypeEncode` error.
Can you help me to resolve the above error?

Complete error list:

```
    the trait bound `ethereum_types::U256: WrapperTypeEncode` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/light-client/src/lib.rs:101:1
    |
101 | #[frame_support::pallet]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `WrapperTypeEncode` is not implemented for `ethereum_types::U256`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `parity_scale_codec::Encode` for `ethereum_types::U256`
note: required by a bound in `EncodeLike`
   --> .cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/parity-scale-codec-3.1.2/src/encode_like.rs:73:25
    |
73  | pub trait EncodeLike<T: Encode = Self>: Sized + Encode {}
    |                         ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `EncodeLike`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `frame_support::pallet` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `ethereum_types::H256: WrapperTypeEncode` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/light-client/src/lib.rs:101:1
    |
101 | #[frame_support::pallet]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `WrapperTypeEncode` is not implemented for `ethereum_types::H256`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `parity_scale_codec::Encode` for `ethereum_types::H256`
note: required by a bound in `EncodeLike`
   --> .cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/parity-scale-codec-3.1.2/src/encode_like.rs:73:25
    |
73  | pub trait EncodeLike<T: Encode = Self>: Sized + Encode {}
    |                         ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `EncodeLike`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `frame_support::pallet` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
warning: `pallet-eth-light-client` (lib) generated 7 warnings
error: could not compile `pallet-eth-light-client` due to 2 previous errors; 7 warnings emitted
```

Comment: Resolved  after updating the version below two crates as
ethereum = { version = "0.12", default-features = false, features = ["with-codec"] }
ethereum-types = { version = "0.13.1", default-features = false, features = ["rlp", "codec"] }

Comment: can you please add this as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Resolved after updating the version below two crates as

```
ethereum = { version = "0.12", default-features = false, features = ["with-codec"] } 
ethereum-types = { version = "0.13.1", default-features = false, features = ["rlp", "codec"] }
```